# Avoid the problem with BigDecimal when migrating to Java 1.4 to Java 1.5+

Tags: java, oracle, bigdecimal

I've recently migrated a Java 1.4 application to a Java 6 environment. Unfortunately, I encountered a problem with the `BigDecimal` storage in a Oracle database. To summarize, when I try to store a `"7.65E+7"` BigDecimal value (`76,500,000.00`) in the database, Oracle stores in reality the value of `7,650,000.00`. This defect is due to the rewritting of the `BigDecimal` class in Java 1.5 (see [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6298816)).

In my code, the `BigDecimal` was created from a `double` using this kind of code:

```
BigDecimal myBD = new BigDecimal("" + someDoubleValue);
someObject.setAmount(myBD);
// Now let Hibernate persists my object in DB...
```

In more than 99% of the cases, everything works fine. Except that in really few case, the bug mentioned above occurs. And that's quite annoying.

If I change the previous code to avoid the use of the String constructor of `BigDecimal`, then I do not encounter the bug *in my uses cases*:

```
BigDecimal myBD = new BigDecimal(someDoubleValue);
someObject.setAmount(myBD);
// Now let Hibernate persists my object in DB...
```

However, how can I be sure that this solution is the correct way to handle the use of `BigDecimal`?

So my question is to know how I have to manage my `BigDecimal` values to avoid this issue:

- Do not use the `new BigDecimal(String)` constructor and use directly the `new BigDecimal(double)`?
- Force Oracle to use `toPlainString()` instead of `toString()` method when dealing with `BigDecimal` (and in this case how to do that)?
- Any other solution?

Environment information:

- Java 1.6.0_14
- Hibernate 2.1.8 (yes, it is a quite old version)
- Oracle JDBC 9.0.2.0 and also tested with 10.2.0.3.0
- Oracle database 10.2.0.3.0

---

**Edit :** I've tested the same code in error but with the Oracle JDBC version 10.2.0.**4**.0 and the bug did **not** occur! The value stored was indeed `76,500,000.00`...
Regarding the [changelog](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/readme_jdbc_10204.html), maybe it is related to the bug #4711863.

Comment: Ouch, nasty behavior change. I'll remember this the next time they say Java goes through hoops on backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Yishai, yes indeed, but they indicate in the given link that `The JSR 13 expert group was aware of the possible compatability issues when changing the definition of toString; however, changing its definition was deemed necessary to reap the other benefits of the JSR.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With modern Hibernate versions you can use UserType to map any class to a database field. Just make a custom UserType and use it to map BigDecimal object to database column.

See http://i-proving.com/space/Technologies/Hibernate/User+Types+in+Hibernate

Answer (score 2):

Confession: I don't personally use Hibernate, but could you just create a subclass MyBigDecimal whose toString() method calls toPlainString()?

I'm also not entirely sure of the merits of passing a double into the cosntructor of BigDecimal -- a double is inherently inaccurate unless the number is composed entirely of additions of powers of 2 (with range restrictions). The whole point of BigDecimal is to circumvent these restrictions on double.

Comment: Hmmm... It doesn't say it is final in the API. And it doesn't appear final for me. I was able to compile it against 1.6. Are you sure @Yishai?

Comment: Juha's answer is the right way to go - you do *not* want to *ever* subclass a Java-defined type if you can help it - there is too much confusion when programmers decide to take it upon themselves to do this.