# migrating Java project from weblogic 8 with java 1.4 to oracle weblogic 12c with java 1.5

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I am working on very a old project ,the technologies used in that project are :

```
Java 1.4,
EJB 1.1
Weblogic 8.1
oracle 11g
```

I am thinking to migrate that project on `oracle weblogic 12c` with `java 1.5` or `java 1.6`.

Can it be possible to migrate that project or not?

Could you please suggest me the possible steps I need to follow to acheive this.

Comment: Yes. It's possible. It will not be "automatic". Why not migrate to an Open Source platform?

Comment: Why go with Java 1.5 or 1.6? Both are quite obsolete.

Comment: WebLogic 8.1 actually supports EJB 2.0. Are you sure that you're using EJB 1.1? Are there any entity beans?

Comment: yes we use ejb 1.1 , yes there are entity beans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to migrate the project. However, you will be required to make code/configuration changes. You will need time to make these changes and to test that everything still works!

Rather than going Java 1.5 or Java 1.6, choose Java 1.7. According to this [Weblogic version table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server#Standards_support_by_version), Weblogic 12c supports Java 1.7.

Migration pointers:

1. From Java 1.5 onwards, `enum` is a reserved word. If `enum` is used anywhere in the Java 1.4 source, you are going to get compile errors complaining about it. You will need to fix all of these errors.
2. Java 1.5 introduced generics, so use of any 1.4 classes that have been made generic in 1.5 will cause compiler warnings. For example: `List stringList = new ArrayList();` will cause a compiler warning in Java 1.5 onwards, and should be re-written appropriately, ie: `List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();` **Note:** these are just warnings, so you don't need to fix them on day 1. It is advised that they get fixed over time though!
3. Update the XML schema references in all your Java EE XML files: `web.xml`, `ejb-jar.xml`, all JSPs, etc. What I mean here is that the schema versions that the project references are very old, you will need to update the schema versions to match the Weblogic 12c column in the [version table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server#Standards_support_by_version). For example, Weblogic 12c supports EJB 3.1 so the root element in `ejb-jar.xml` should now be declared as follows: `<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">`. Do this for all Java EE XML files. After doing this, you'll may have some XML validations problems that you'll need to fix. Read the documentation and fix accordingly.
4. Update your IDE to refer to the appropriate versions of each Java EE specification, as defined in the [versions table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server#Standards_support_by_version). Likely you'll get a bunch of errors that you'll need to fix. Fix them!

There will be more than what I've mentioned above. That said, don't be scared of doing the migration. Give yourself plenty of time (1 week for a small project, 4 weeks for a large project), and carefully start migrating. Remember to read the documentation!

Good luck! :)

Comment: One of the biggest changes (and so, PITA) in migrating from 1.4 to Java SE 5 is the new BigDecimal.toString() method behavior. For more details, see [Avoid the problem with BigDecimal when migrating to Java 1.4 to Java 1.5+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622948/avoid-the-problem-with-bigdecimal-when-migrating-to-java-1-4-to-java-1-5)

Comment: I need to know whether I can use weblogic 12c with current jdk as well or not?

Comment: @Suman I *think* you should be fine running Weblogic 12c on Java 8. I'm not aware of any Java 8 API changes that conflict with existing Java 7 code (ie the 12c code).

Comment: Thanks #Mule , but my question was regarding jdk 1.4 , which I am currently using

Comment: @Suman No, 12c is not going work with Java 1.4.

Comment: @Suman, current versions of WebLogic 12c are only supported and certified for JDK 6 and 7 (not even 5, and definitely not 1.4).